# Problema usando RegExp y replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy remplazando texto de un párrafo pero cuando me encuentro caracteres especiales como **(*,? u otros)** en lugar de remplazarlo, lo adiciona. Les dejo el código para ver si me pueden ayudar.

> Nota: aquí solo coloco un pequeño ejemplo pero me sucede siempre que
>   encuentra un carácter especial.

```js
var search = "LEYES PARA EL OCÉANO*";
var regex = new RegExp(search,'g');
$("#uno").html($("#uno").text().replace(regex,'<span style="color: #FF0000; font-size: 18px;">'+search+'</span>'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Texto original:(LEYES PARA EL OCÉANO*)</p>
<p id="uno">LEYES PARA EL OCÉANO*</p>
```

Comment: No me queda claro que es lo que buscas reemplazar

Comment: Lo que quiero remplazar es la cadena superior tal y como esta pero cuando lo hago me agrega un carácter especial.

Comment: Lo qué tienes en la variable `search` es igual a lo que está contenido en la etiqueta `<p id="uno">` además, es una simple cadena, no es una expresión regular, así que sigo diciendo que no entiendo que es lo que quieres reemplazar

Comment: El contenido que tengo en la variable search, si es el mismo que tengo en la etiqueta y lo quiero cambiar a color rojo, tal y como esta en la variable search pero lo que me sucede cuando cambio a rojo que me agrega un (*) o cualquier otro carácter especial que encuentre.

Comment: @YoelRodriguez Por eso estoy sugiriendo esa pregunta como duplicada. Al usar la función de esa respuesta en `var regex = new RegExp(escaparRegex(search),'g');` coincidiría correctamente

Comment: Ok no hay problema si considera que se deba quitar lo puede hacer

Comment: @YoelRodriguez No se está quitando nada, se te está intentando ayudar de la mejor manera. Esa función convierte cualquier texto en una expresión regular que coincide con el texto literal

Comment: Coincido con @Mariano, aunque en mi respuesta te haya explicado el problema y cual es la base para solucionarlo de una forma directa. La pregunta que asocia Mariano aunque no sea un duplicado de la tuya, comparten una solución. Hay que escapar la cadena de búsqueda y la respuesta a esa pregunta aporta una buena solución. Puedes verlo incluso como un complemento, una persona te ha indicado cual es el problema que estás teniendo y en otra respuesta de este mismo sitio tienes un modo estupendo de solucionarlo!

Comment: Fui a la respuesta que ud me envió y me sigue agregando el * así como también la respuesta y me lo sigue colocando y le dije que si deseaba quitar podía por que es ilógico que existan preguntas repetida

Comment: Perdón señores no estoy molesto con lo que me dicen creo que se me mal interpreto lo que estoy tratando de evitar es que existan preguntas que no estén debidamente formuladas y se incremente en la base de datos por gusto

Comment: @YoelRodriguez la pregunta está bien formulada, y no se va a eliminar, sólo se está marcando dónde se puede ver una respuesta a tu pregunta.. Se explica en [¿Por qué algunas preguntas son marcadas como duplicadas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: Muchas gracias porque me sirvió para ver mi error que no lo lograba ver y consistía en que avía copiado el texto de word y avía colocado un carácter raro que no veía si no es por la ayuda que me dieron no lo hubiese visto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que el caracter '*' es un caracter reservado para expresiones regulares y resulta interpretado al realizar el reemplazo.

Si no te interesa utilizar expresiones regulares, puedes reemplazar directamente:

```js
var search = "LEYES PARA EL OCÉANO*";
    $("#uno").html($("#uno").text().replace(search,'<span style="color: #FF0000; font-size: 18px;">'+search+'</span>'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Texto original:(LEYES PARA EL OCÉANO*)</p>
<p id="uno">LEYES PARA EL OCÉANO*</p>
```

Si por el contrario quieres usar expresiones regulares, los caracteres que no quieres que la expresión regular los reemplaze, tienes que escaparlos.

```js
    var search = "LEYES PARA EL OCÉANO\\*";
    var regex = new RegExp(search,'g');
    $("#uno").html($("#uno").text().replace(regex,'<span style="color: #FF0000; font-size: 18px;">'+search.replace('\\','')+'</span>'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Texto original:(LEYES PARA EL OCÉANO*)</p>
<p id="uno">LEYES PARA EL OCÉANO*</p>
```

Comment: La opción de escape no me esta trabajando porque cuando trato de colocar \\ en el ckeditor me deja solo una y el remplazo directo me sigue dejando el * estos datos yo los tengo en una BD pudiera ser eso el problema

Comment: lo acabo de resolver muchas gracias a todos los que me ayudaron el problema era que había un carácter que delante del * que no se veía en el ckeditor ya que el texto lo había copiado de word lo pase a notepad++ y lo vi muchas gracias a todos por su ayuda.

Comment: Me alegro de que te sirviera! ;)